# Inbox "see all" option shows wrong page when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

**See all** option in **inbox** Stack Exchange portal link redirects to top questions and answers and not to inbox related stuff (I guess it should be activity or something like that).

[image: Stack Exchange global dropdown screenshot]

Comment: Odd, I am getting the correct URL, like `http://stackexchange.com/users/[...]?tab=inbox`

Comment: So: what URL do you get?

Comment: Same as in your first comment but shouldn't it redirect you to activity rather than top questions and answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed. If you're not logged into [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com), the `?tab=inbox` ("see all") link now redirects you to the login page. After logging in, you'll be redirected back to your inbox.

If you already have a stackexchange.com account, global auth should kick in, and the login/redirects will happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see your user name in the top bar on [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com?)?

I guess you're simply not logged in. I cannot see *your* Inbox either, if I go to *your* [`?tab=inbox`](https://stackexchange.com/users/e90d9fa8-557b-4d2d-b194-1b3bdd684375?tab=inbox) URL, and then [see your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR1gp.png) instead.

Comment: No, I'm not logged in. It seems that this is the problem.

Comment: However, isn't the activity tab more appropriate in this case?

Comment: I guess you should be automatically logged in, @yojimbo87? (In normal usage, people won't have a link to someone else's Inbox. So even an error page would be fine if I would try to see your Inbox. But in your case, you're following a link from your own Inbox. Would be nice if it could log you in on the fly.)